# How get BQL (bLOOMBERG) query from python

Tags: python-3.x, bloomberg

I have the following query in Excel using BQL:

=BQL("MEMBERS('INEMCBI LX Equity',type=holdings)";"name";"cols=2;rows=223")

This shows a table of securities of a specific mutual fund. Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH7zP.png)

I want to get the same information using python in Dataframe structure but I dont know any way to get it.

Comment: This is what you need:  https://pypi.org/project/pdblp/

Comment: That is a wrapper for the blpapi. It doesn't give you the same abilities as BQNT. It is more for the =BDP and =BDH Excel equivalents.

Answer (score 5):

Run BQNT on your Bloomberg terminal to ensure the BQL environment is installed.

Follow the steps exactly as followed.

Open file explorer

- Navigate to C:\blp\bqnt\environments\bqnt-3\Lib\site-packages and copy these folders:
- bqapi
- bqbreg
- bql
- bqlmetadata
- bqrequest
- bqutil
- ciso8601

4. Paste them to your python installation folder %userprofile%\Anaconda3\envs{mypythonenv}\lib\site-packages\

Then you can test this code in your code editor. I use Vscode.

```
import seaborn as sb
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import bql

bq = bql.Service()
query = """get(px_last)for('AAPL US EQUITY')with(dates=range(-1y,0d),fill='prev')"""
data = bql.combined_df(bq.execute(query)).reset_index()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sb.lineplot(data=data, x='DATE',y='px_last')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Does this still work for you in January 2023?  I'm getting a 'no module named 'bqmonitor'' error when i follow the steps exactly as you say.  Are there other folders to copy after their latest updates?

I copied them to %userprofile%\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\
%userprofile%\Anaconda3\envs{mypythonenv}\lib\site-packages\
as envs was empty.

Comment: Just copy this module as well and others that will be required

Comment: Yes, this is still working at Sept 2023. There have been updates, so there's quite a few more packages to copy over. If you don't have environments, or just want to install it for all environments, just copy to %userprofile%\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\

Answer (score 3):

If you run `BQNT<GO>` on the terminal, you'll get access to Python BQL examples, but the examples won't work outside of BQNT. Since you mention using `=BQL`, I'm assuming you have access to a terminal.

Example in BQNT:

```py
import bql
bq = bql.Service()
fund = bq.univ.members("INEMCBI LX Equity", type="HOLDINGS")
name = bq.data.name()
req = bql.Request(fund, {"Fund Holdings": name})
res = bq.execute(req)
data = res[0].df()
data
```

Comment: Thanks @NikT ! I thought I would add a little to this that may help others. Since BQNT is sandboxed, you cannot save to the usual local drive places. However, I did find that you can save to the sandboxed project folder, for me it was 'C:/Users/my_user/AppData/Local/bipy/.....'. BQNT has pathlib in the environment, so just run pathlib.Path.cwd() and you will find the folder that you can write to. I wanted to pickle something to use in my own app.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `blp` package from Matthew Gilbert. Currently, it's accessible exclusively through GitHub:

```
> pip install git+https://github.com/matthewgilbert/blp.git
```

```py
from blp import blp

bquery = blp.BlpQuery().start()

bquery.bql(expression="get(name) for(holdings('INEMCBI LX Equity'))")
```

This is an undocumented endpoint, so we haven't yet fully grasped its behavior. If anyone comes across any bugs, please feel free to open a GitHub issue.

TIP: For an easy way to create this expression, try Excel's BQL Builder in Advanced View. After previewing the query, you can just "Copy BQL Query String Only."