# BQL/BQNT visualizations in Python?

Tags: python, bloomberg

I saw this post -- [How get BQL (bLOOMBERG) query from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827337/how-get-bql-bloomberg-query-from-python)

And wondering how I can get the bqviz packages, the visualization tools available in BQNT (on the terminal sandboxed version) in my own python instance. Any ideas? Thanks!

I tried copying various packages from the bqnt site-packages folder. I am able to get bql services, though not the visualizations. Thanks!

Comment: Bqviz doesn't work outside of bqnt. You can use bqplot though.

Comment: Thanks @Akdemy. Do you know why not? I (maybe naively) imagine you could copy over all of the files/packages no? Thx

Comment: It's like bqwidgets, which is also only available on BQNT. Of course could you copy all the code, that's works with every programme. You just cannot find anything outside BQNT. You'll just need too find all files in a sandboxed environment.